# Swift get vs _read

Tags: swift, readonly, access-control, subscript

What's the difference between the following 2 subscripts?

```swift
subscript(position: Int) {
    get { ... }
}
```

```swift
subscript(position: Int) {
    _read { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`_read` is part of the Swift Ownership story that has been in development for a while now. Since `read` (the likely name once it goes through Swift Evolution) is fairly advanced concept of the language you will probably want to read at least where it is described in the Ownership Manifesto [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/OwnershipManifesto.md#generalized-accessors) to get a more full answer than I'll provide here.

It is an alternative to `get` on subscripts that allows you to `yield` a value instead of `return` a value. This is essential for move only types because they cannot be copied (that is their entire purpose) which is what happens when you `return` a value. By using `read` it makes it so you could have for example have an `Array` of move only types and still use the values in it without taking the ownership of them by moving them. The easiest (and not technically correct since it is a coroutine) way to conceptually think about it is that you get a pointer to the object that `read` `yields`.

The sibling of `read` is `modify` which is currently in the pitch phase of Swift Evolution [here](https://forums.swift.org/t/modify-accessors/31872) so that can also give you some helpful insight into what `read` is since it is a coroutine as well.

So for now if Xcode gives you a `_read` to implement simply change it to `get` since it is a bug since it isn't an official part of the language yet.

Comment: What is the status of this in 2024?